# “Cancellation fee” deriving from “Annullierung”

Tags: single-word-request

Is there a German word for *cancellation fee* in German that derives from *Annullierung*?

Answer (score 4):

Yes.

As you already found out, »Annullierung« is a valid translation of »cancellation«. It's not the only one valid translation, also »Stornierung« is possible (and more often used).

Translations of »fee« are »Gebühr« or »Abgabe«, but here, »Gebühr« is the better choice.

If you put things together, you get this:

> Annullierungsgebühr

This is what you are looking for.

Other translations of »cancellation fee« are:

- Annullierungsabgabe
- Stornierungsgebühr
- Stornierungsabgabe

But as said before, Abgabe is not the best choice in this case.

There is another word, that derives from Stornierungsgebühr. It is

- Stornogebühr

Comment: Thanks! I guess it is Annullierung with double n and double l.

Answer (score 4):

We'd usually use *"Stornierung"* in this case, so it would be *"Stornierungsgebühr"* (or shorter *"Stornogebühr"*). *"Annullieren"* is used relative rarely, mostly in cases of legal issues like *"ein Gerichtsurteil annullieren"*, *"einen Vertrag annullieren"*, *"eine Ehe annullieren"*, but also (outside of legal issues) as *"der Flug wurde annulliert"*. That a fee is associated with such an act is even rarer, so I don't think a word exists. While a word could technically be created by merging, e.g. *"Annullierungsgebühr"* or *"Annullierungskosten"*, it certainly wouldn't be commonly used.

Comment: Thanks! I guess it is Annullierung with double n and double l.

Comment: Yep, right, I fixed the two typos.

Comment: *Stornogebühr* should be by far the most commonly used form.